# Extract specific text from string with single quotes using java

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract specific string from entire query.
Here is my query

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT t1.id_numeric,t1.id_text FROM t1, ( SELECT t2.id_numeric,t2.test_number FROM t2 GROUP BY t2.column4) selected WHERE t1.id_numeric = t2.test_number AND t1.test_number = selected.test_number AND t1.component_name = selected.component_name AND lims.insert_timestamp = selected.insert_timestamp) as fhr_lims_pinebend WHERE ( ( sampled_date >= '2018-02-17 15:24:59') AND ( sampled_date <= '2018-02-17 15:27:00') ) ORDER BY sampled_date ASC;
```

From this query I want to extract only below part

```
') AND ( sampled_date <= '
```

can anyone suggest me correct regex to get that. I tried couple of but getting issues with single quote which I tried to remove but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
AND\s\(\ssampled_date\s<=\s'
```

but refer regex basics first insted of just using this

Comment: yeah it worked. Thank you for your quick response @Anushka